# Getting SQL view output as xml ( is it even possible ? )

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2000

I have a massive view and using a SQL query I want to produce output as XML.

So if I query SQL it gives me back XML.

I have no idea how to do it so please point me in right direction.

SADLY it's for SQL Server **2000**

Comment: [FOR XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163782.aspx) doesn't work for you?

Comment: [MSFT link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163782.aspx#S1)

Comment: -1 for lack of research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FOR XML RAW` It returns XML.

Like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name FOR XML RAW;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, it is supported in SQL Server 2000: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163782.aspx